# Problems with automatic identity generation using JPA2 on HSQLDB

Tags: oracle, jpa-2.0, hsqldb, liquibase

I have a setup where the Oracle database (12c) is used in production and HSQLDB (in memory) is used for test cases. I use Liquibase for updating the database.

I have the following class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SYSTEM")
public class System {

    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "BIGINT")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 40)
    @Column(name = "NAME", columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2")
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 16)
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "TOKEN", columnDefinition = "VARBINARY")
    private UUID token;
}
```

The Liquibase definition I use for this table is:

```
"createTable": {
    "tableName": "SYSTEM",
    "columns": [
        {
           "column": {
               "name": "ID",
               "type": "BIGINT",
               "autoIncrement": true,
               "constraints": {
                   "primaryKey": true
               }
           }
       },
       {
           "column": {
               "name": "NAME",
               "type": "VARCHAR2(40)",
               "constraints": {
                   "nullable": false
               }
           }
       },
       {
           "column": {
               "name": "TOKEN",
               "type": "RAW(16)",
               "constraints": {
                   "nullable": false
               }
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

When creating a new system using an EntityManager.persist on the Oracle database this works. A row is inserted in the database and the ID field is populated with a value as expected.

On the HSQLDB database this doesn't happen. And to me it looks like the automatic generation isn't triggered.

The SQL executed by HSQLDB to create the SYSTEM table is:

```
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC."SYSTEM" (ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL, TOKEN RAW(16) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_SYSTEM PRIMARY KEY (ID))
```

Is there a know bug in HSQLDB or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If it would be a bug, _h2 database_ would be an alternative - also w.r.t. Liquibase. It even has an Oracle compatibility mode.

Comment: If it's a bug or if I can't find a solution I will try out h2. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `;sql.syntax_ora=true` to the end of the JDBC connection URL.

With an in-memory database, you also need to make sure the same Java process is used to update the database and to query it. If two separate processes are used, the database made by the first process disappear when the process exits.

Comment: `;sql.syntax_ora=true` is in the connection URL so that doesn't change things, I'm afraid. But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: To find out more, run HSQLDB as a server with the setting `server.silent=false` to show the SQL that is executed.

Comment: I tried `server.silent=false` but for some reason that didn't work. Instead I tried `hsqldb.sqllog=2` and the SQL was printed. I have edited my question to include the SQL.

Comment: Check the SQL that inserts into the table. You can use `hsqldb.sqllog=3` to get more details with prepared statement execution.

Comment: I have found the problem and i wasn't in hsqldb. Something as simple as a missing transaction in my code. So it works now after I added a transaction. I am sorry for wasting your time with this question.